# Passing NSString* to a C++ reference parameter

Tags: c++, objective-c

Have an Objective-C++ function. (The file has the correct .mm extension).

```
int SPGetNumericAttribute(NSMutableString* line, NSString* &attr) {...}
```

Some code calls as follows:

```
NSString* queryAttr = nil;
int res = SPGetNameAttribute(line, queryAttr); <-- error
```

Compiler complains:

> No matching function call for 'SPGetNameAttribute'.

Is there a technical reason why you can't pass an Objective-C object to a C++ reference parameter?
My guess is something to do with ARC.

Comment: so first you show declaration of SPGetNumericAttribute function and then you show how you call SPGetNameAttribute function. Which one is correct?

Comment: SPGetNameAttribute() declaration compiles without any errors. Calling SPGetNameAttribute() and the compiler complains. You can declare a reference to an NSObject*, but can't pass one. Why?

Comment: Please show the declaration of SPGetNameAttribute. I want to see what this function look like. What you show now is declaration of a different function named SPGetNumericAttribute

Answer (score 0):

ARC needs to know how to handle the reference counting of the second parameter inside of the function. By default the parameter has autoreleasing type. Thus your variable `queryAttr` must have the autoreleasing ARC type

```
__autoreleasing NSString* queryAttr = nil;
```

or alternatively you can declare your function as

```
int SPGetNumericAttribute(NSMutableString* line, NSString* __strong &attr) { ... }
```

and the error disappears for strong variables. Tests with Instruments show that ARC seems to be handling this right, too. But then you may only use strong variables for this parameter.

I think it should be better, if you use a pointer instead:

```
int SPGetNumericAttribute(NSMutableString* line, NSString** attr) { ... }
```